# Unable to enable LDAP authentication on GPFS / Spectrum Scale file system

Tags: active-directory, ldap, filesystems, samba

I have setup a GPFS / Spectrum Scale cluster on 2 RHEL7 nodes.  On that cluster I have created a filesystem.  I want to enable LDAP based authentication with kerberos so that I can NFSv4 ACLs to control access

On the management node of the GPFS / Spectrum Scale cluster I run the following command:

```
mmuserauth service create --type ldap --data-access-method file --servers 9.xxx.xxx.xxx --base-dn dc=test,dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=com --user-name cn=bind,dc=test,dc=sub,dc=domain,dc=com  --password xxxxxxx --netbios-name host1 --enable-kerberos --kerberos-server 9.xxx.xxx.xxx --kerberos-realm test.sub.domain.com
```

I receive the following error:

```
Either failed to create a samba domain entry on LDAP server if not present or could not read the already existing samba domain entry from the
Detailed message:smbldap_search_domain_info: Adding domain info for host1 failed with NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
pdb backend ldapsam:ldap://9.xxx.xxx.xxx did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)
WARNING: Could not open passdb

File authentication configuration failed.

mmuserauth service create: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.
```

I have googled around trying to find a fix but unable to.  The Active Directory server it is trying to connect to has the LDAP Unix extensions installed on it to allow for LDAP authentication to be enabled on clients that use it.

GPFS only allows kerberos to be enabled when using LDAP for authentication.  When AD is used for authentication there isnt an option for Kerberos to be enabled.

Unfortunately for me, in order to get NFSv4 ACLs to work properly I need to have kerberos working.

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message suggested, i.e. create a SAMBA domain (Or is this error related to your fictitious IP?). Have you had any luck using LDAP through standard mechanisms? LDAP extensions through AD should be used cautiously, especially in conjunction with Kerberos.

Comment: @Claris the IP address I submitted was edited so as to not display anything private.  I am trying to verify whether the SAMBA domain is setup correctly or not.

Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running Active Directory in your infrastructure you should integrate Spectrum Scale with Active Directory using the *--type ad* option of the *"mmuserauth service create"* command. Additionally since the UNIX extensions are populated on Active Directory you should also pass in the  *"--unixmap-domains"* CLI option to help pull the UID / GID from UNIX attributes.

Spectrum Scale 4.2 supports Kerberized NFSv4 as well.
Support matrix --> 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/STXKQY_4.2.0/com.ibm.spectrum.scale.v4r2.ins.doc/bl1ins_authconcept.htm

Since the GPFS filesystem has been configured for NFSv4 ACL's it will reprsent all the ACL in NFSv4 style. Kerberized NFS is not necessary to utilize this ability.